# Make SQL query secure - getting values from $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

I am using this code for updating fields inside a mysql table.

```
foreach ($_POST['changed'] as $SubArray) {
    foreach ($SubArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'recid') continue;

        $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE clients SET $key = '$value' WHERE id = $SubArray[recid]");
        $STH->execute();
    }    
}
```

I think that the variables like `$key`, `$value` and `$SubArray[recid]` inside the query are very unsecured. Is there a way to make this secure, that no unwanted code is getting inside the query by `$_POST`?

**(calling the columns with placeholders is not possible, because I dont know the column-names from the table)**

Comment: You're using prepare with variables?? What's the point?
Consider reading about the usage of prepared statements. (using placeholders for instance)

Comment: Firstly, you can't call columns with placeholders at all - you can only bind values. But you can create a whitelist of known-good column names, and make sure that `$key` is in that array. Secondly, you can still bind the values, as @OfirBaruch says, and that will also help make your code more secure.

Answer (score 0):

With [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) it's a piece of cake:

```
include 'safemysql.class.php';
$db = new safeMysql();

$allowed = array('name', 'surname', 'all the fields you want to save');

foreach ($_POST['changed'] as $SubArray)
{
    $insert = $db->filterArray($SubArray, $allowed);
    $db->query("UPDATE clients SET ?u WHERE id = ?s", $insert, $SubArray['recid']);
}
```

while with defective PDO it will take you a lot more trouble.
First, you will need to take yourself a function to create a **list of values** dynamically, as no sane developer would update fields one by one:

```
function pdoSet($fields, &$values, $source = array()) {
    $set = '';
    $values = array();
    if (!$source) $source = &$_POST;
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (isset($source[$field])) {
            $set.="`".str_replace("`","``",$field)."`". "=:$field, ";
            $values[$field] = $source[$field];
        }
    }
    return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

and now you may start with running your updates

```
$allowed = array('name', 'surname', 'all the fields you want to save');
foreach ($_POST['changed'] as $SubArray)
{
    $set = pdoSet($allowed, $values, $SubArray);
    $sql = "UPDATE clients SET $set WHERE id = :id";
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $values["id"] = $SubArray['recid'];
    $stm->execute($values);
}
```

To answer a question from comments:

First of all, a developer who don't know his fields is a nonsense. It just can't be. A free-form application like phpmyadmin is a rare exception and this is apparently not the case.

After all, it is matter of security. 2 dangers are coming from a free-form array:

1. There could be fields in the table which a customer is not allowed to. And you surely will reuse this code to let a customer edit their details. So, it is much better to always know fields you have to update.
2. A plain SQL injection through named placeholders (as you may notice they are going straight from the user input untouched).

So, if you are 100% sure that no artificial field can be added - you may omit this check, but you put yourself in a constant danger. And this thing with str_replace have to be used on the field names anyway, while positional (?) placeholders have to be used instead of named ones.

Comment: thanks for your solution - on this line `$allowed = array('name', 'surname', 'all the fields you want to save');` i have to set up the column(s)(names). but what should i do when i dont know the column(s)(names)?

Answer (score 0):

This will be safe **only** if you're making sure that the value of `$key` is safe.
For instance:

```
$approved = array('fname', 'lname' ,'email');
foreach ($_POST['changed'] as $SubArray) {
    foreach ($SubArray as $key => $value) {
       // if ($key === 'recid') continue; (Since we're using in_array - no need in this line)
         if(in_array($key , $approved))
         {
           //$key is safe: 
               $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE clients SET $key = :value WHERE id = :id");
               $STH->execute(array(':value' => $value , ':id' => $SubArray['recid']));
         }

      }    
}
```

**UPDATE**
Please notice that you're using a loop inside a loop,
in order to be more efficient , consider changing your code.

Comment: $key can be "protected" by making sure it's has a certain value (look at the condition before the statement)

Comment: this condition doesn't make anything certain

Comment: You're right , added a "condition" that will make my solution legit.

Comment: and so you're going to run all this stuff in a loop?

Comment: `filterArray` is a loop as well (https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php#L403). isn't it?

Comment: ALL this stuff you wrote here, I mean.

Comment: Oh , of course not. will edit the answer so it would be clear.

Comment: To me, you made it worse. What is this line with `continue` for?

Comment: Oh, you missed my question a bit. May be I didn't make myself clear. I were asking what is this line for, not where it come from.